# node.getNodeType is not working as expected in case of ELEMENT_NODE

Tags: java, xml, w3c, xmlnode

I am trying to fetch all the elemnt type node only , and then i have some specific operation to do , but the node.getNodeType is not working as expected in case of ELEMENT_NODE - it is going in if block for all child node

Sample xml -

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.05">
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>00990119071512383635</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2019-07-15T12:38:36.304+05:30</CreDtTm>
            <InitgPty>
                <Nm>appSend</Nm>
            </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
....
```

here is my code -  what I want to do is for elements like **MsgId** i want to do something and for **GrpHdr**  i want do some different operation

```
  try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
                dbf.setValidating(true);
                dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
                dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new File(fileName));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                    node.normalize();

                    if( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ){
                        // do operation for only elements
                    }else{
                        // do other operation for non elements 
                    }


                }

            }catch (Exception e){

            }
```

Does anybody have faced similar issue ,

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

well , the following isn't a good workaround - but this is how i fixed it

Elements - will have just one child always.

So i tweaked it with below code -

```
  if( node.getChildNodes().getLength() != 1 ){
                        // do operation for only non - elements
                    }else{
                        // do other operation for elements 
                    }
```

I would say this is just a work around, not a good solution